# Genome Assembly Using Reads

Tags: bioinformatics

I'm taking an online bioinformatics class and I am stuck on a problem. The resources I have found don't help that much. Here is the problem:

"Assemble the error-free reads from a circular genome on the dataset below. You do not need to consider the reverse complement of the reads.

Dataset: CGTTCT CTAG GACGT TAGAC

**As the reads do not have the same length, convert the reads to 4-mers using the approach proposed by Idury and Waterman**."

I believe this means I need to convert this into sets of 4 characters each. Do I simply break them up by taking the first 4 characters and last 4 characters like this?

CGTTCT: CGTT --> TTCT
CTAG: CTAG --> CTAG
GACGT: GACG --> ACGT
TAGAC: TAGA --> AGAC

And end up with a new dataset of: "CGTT TTCT CTAG GACG ACGT TAGA AGAC"?

Or is there more to it than that? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I would guess that it would be all 4mers. In this case that would mean that CGTTCT would also yield GTTC. But as I say - this is a guess.

Comment: It does in fact mean all possible 4mers. I don't know how much material you get from the course, but they refer to this paper: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.79.6459&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: To be sure I'm understanding correctly, does that mean the new dataset should be: "CGTT GTTC TTCT CTAG GACG ACGT TAGA AGAC"?

Answer (score 3):

Actually the new data set will be,

for k = 4 ([k-mer value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-mer))

CGTTCT -> CGTT GTTC TTCT

or

[image]

Source: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2874646/